# node how to convert url from c:\\Projects\\a\ to localhost:8080/uploads/

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node express on `src` folder and I have a node script which return an an image with the following path:

```
c:\\Projects\\a\\b\\c\\src\\uploads\\ff41d239-1f16-463e-99fd-9053490cb6a6/File-repair.png
```

I need using node to convert previous URL in a similar url:

```
http://localhost:8080/uploads/ff41d239-1f16-463e-99fd-9053490cb6a6/File-repair.png
```

I would rather prefer using regex or string manipulation if possible.

How can achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

this?

```js
var str = 'c:\\Projects\\a\\b\\c\\src\\uploads\\ff41d239-1f16-463e-99fd-9053490cb6a6/File-repair.png';

console.log( 'http://localhost:8080/'+ /\\src\\(.*)$/.exec(str)[1].replace(/\\/g,'/') )
```